# if $_POST contains anything other than text do

Tags: php, if-statement, post, output, contains

I have a post data coming from a different page then this php code handles the data and saves it in a text file.

I want the data from `$_POST['first']` to be saved if and only if its text ( doesnt contain a numbers or special characters)

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("/var/things.txt", "a+");

$txt = "1st:".$_POST['first'];

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Comment: Did you spend any time at all Googling this? If so, was it less than 30 seconds?

Comment: _And how have you attempted to achieve your_ ___want??___

Comment: and have you a form for this?

Comment: What do you consider to be a special character ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly you forgot => `?` => "want?".

Comment: spaces? commas? full stops? hyphen?

Comment: @RiggsFolly *"And how have you attempted to achieve your **want*** => *"And how have you attempted to achieve your **want?***

Comment: @MarkBaker and punctuations.... etc. etc.

Comment: I did spend time, I'm very new to PHP, I just want ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ (upper & lower)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it has any special character:

```
if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $_POST['first'])){
   //if string contains special characters.
}
```

Check if the string contains numbers:

```
if(1 === preg_match('~[0-9]~', $_POST['first'])){
   //if string contains special numbers.
}
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please check it as solved?